# How to create an RDD from another RDD by extracting specific values?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD which contains a String and JSON object (as String). I extracted required values from the JSON object. How can I use the values to create a new RDD which stores each value in each column?

RDD

```
(1234,{"id"->1,"name"->"abc","age"->21,"class"->5})
```

From which a map was generated as shown below.

```
"id"->1,
"name"->"abc",
"age"->21

"id"->2,
"name"->"def",
"age"->31
```

How to convert this to RDD[(String, String, String)], which stores data like:

```
1   abc  21
2   def  31
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Can you please start here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to provide a Minimal, [Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help

Comment: You want to convert what type to an RDD[(String,String,String)] ?

Comment: RDD[(String, String)]

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of that RDD with something like rdd.take(10).foreach(println) ?

Comment: (1234,{"id"->1,"name"->"abc","age"->21})

Comment: Try this rdd1.first and please update your question to information and don't add them as comments !

Comment: if you have RDD[Map[String, String]] then you can just use `.map` I suppose? Something like `myRDD.map(x => (x.get("id"), x.get("name"), x.get("age"))`? Or I don't understand the question?

Comment: The issue is that he doesn't have and RDD of Map String which means * I extracted required values from the JSON object* is misleading because he didn't !

Comment: You `map` from your `RDD[(String, String)]` to `RDD[Map[String, String]]` by dropping the first element of a tuple and converting the second element of a tuple to a Map, then get its values into another tuple. Or you deserialise json into an intermediate case class and transform it to the tuple. Or you just extract values from json and form a tuple. It is all the same.

Comment: Which is the best way to transform RDD[(String, String)] to RDD[Map[String, String]] ?

Answer (score 1):

Not in front of a compiler right now, but something like this should work:

```
def parse(val row: (String, JValue)) : Seq((String, String, String)) = {
  // Here goes your code to parse a Json into a sequence of tuples, seems like you have this already well in hand.
}

val rdd1 = ??? // Initialize your RDD[(String, JValue)]
val rdd2: RDD[(String, String, String)] = rdd1.flatMap(parse)
```

`flatMap` does the trick, as your extraction function can extract multiple rows on each Json input (or none) and they will be seamlessly be integrated into the final RDD.